# How do I extract images from an unknown file? (might be an .SO)

Tags: android, extract, hexadecimal, img

I have a file taken from an apk of an old videogame made for an old android phone. It has no file extension and is simply titled "images". MediaFire reads it as an .SO file, but I don't know if it's correct. 7zip just reads it as archive. I ran it through Filext giving a bunch of random text along with lines like "/button_1.png," "/button_2.png," "/char/slime0.png," etc, which look like file locations. I also put it into a hex editor which [showed this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TRqj.png). It seems it contains IMG files as it's shown each time at the beginning of each file location. The end of the hex simply states "END". Is there any way to extract the images? Do I have to run the apk for it to decompile?

Comment: Not sure if this would work but could you copy the file and set the extension to .jpg or .png?

Comment: If 7-Zip sees the file as an archive, is it able to unpack it?

Comment: Just run PhotoRec on the file. If there are images in a common format PhotoRec will extract them.

Answer (score 0):

.so files are shared object files (on linux/unix systems). I doubt that the .so file contains the images that you are looking for, itself.

if this is an android apk, then I would suggest using APKtool to decompile it; it should be able to get you the images, along with everything else split out of the apk into files/folders.

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

There are some online apk decompilers too, but I have no recommendations. I've used APKtool, but none of the online tools.

Comment: I decompiled it and couldn't find the images. All I could find were text (XML), code files (java,) and a dex file. Could they be in the .dex file? Ran it through FileExt and it says it's a Dalvik EXecutable showing a list with the image locations again.
I also opened Art.java and hovered over the instances it gave a .png. This error popped up: https://i.imgur.com/2gCINV9.png.

Comment: No, they wouldn't be in the .dex file - they dex file contains things like class list, method list, etc. java / bytecode related things... are you sure these images are apart of the app? or could they be sourcing something in android?

Comment: also, it might be helpful if i knew what the app is - i could try looking at it myself, maybe.

Comment: Sure, it's a game called Legend of the Chambered created by Markus Persson. It's one of many variants he created: https://web.archive.org/web/20120121083531/http://mojang.com/m/LoC_android.apk